# How to check type is timestamp in dictionary?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
       {
        "request_emp": {
            "id": 2
        },
        "overtime_date": "2021-05-26",
        "mail_body": "werr",
        "mail_status": 0,
        "mail_subject": "er",
        "request_start_datetime": "2021-05-26T00:00:00Z",
        "request_end_datetime": "2021-05-26T00:00:00Z",
        "request_total_datetime": null,
        "actual_start_datetime": null,
        "actual_end_datetime": null,
        "actual_total_datetime": null,
        "del_flag": 0
      }
```

how to check attribute which has datetime type value in above dict?

Comment: `type(mydict["request_start_datetime"])`?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a RegEx to check whenever it is a dateime type value.

Comment: The question seems poorly phrased, but asks about the _type_ of values, not whether they're valid timestamp strings. Assuming the OP actually wants to know which values can be converted into timestamps, you should be recommending libraries like datetime or dateparser rather than sending someone into the minefield/rabbit hole that is regex, or at least starting from whether the timestamp formats are consistent.